# How can I obtain an array from the string "[1, 12, 2, 3, 4]"?

Tags: javascript

In my JSP, a hidden variable value shows as following.

```
<input type="hidden" name="" value="[1, 12, 2, 3, 4]" id="rollNumber"/>
```

When I try to get hidden variable in javascript function by `document.getElementById` and put it in a array (`rollNo`) as follows:

```
rollNo = document.getElementById("rollNumber").value;
```

`rollNo` value is coming as `[1, 12, 2, 3, 4]`

When I try to iterate `rollNo` it gives me elements as:

```
[
1
,
space
1
2
, 
space  etc... elements
```

I need only elements like `'1 12 2 3 4'`

Comment: document.getElementById _does_ return the correct element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by just using a simple regular expression

```
var text = document.getElementById("rollNumber").value; 
var pattern = /\d+/g // matches all instances of one or more digits
var result = text.match(pattern)
```

simple and elegant, is valid for all string containing digits, with any separators

Comment: +1 You forgot to convert it to a Number for him ;)

How about extending String.prototype so he can simply write `var x="rollNumber".getRoll(2);` haha

Answer (score 4):

You will need to parse the string value that is returned into a javascript array. You could use the `JSON.parse` method:

```
var rollNo = document.getElementById("rollNumber").value; 
var values = JSON.parse(rollNo);
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var item = values[i];
}
```

Remark: the `JSON.parse` method is built into modern browsers but if you need to support legacy browsers you could include the [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) script to your page.

Answer (score 3):

- Your input field has the string value `"[1, 12, 2, 3, 4]"`.
- Just because arrays can be stringized to look similar doesn't mean that this string is magically an array.

---

You could use `eval` to turn that stringized Javascript literal into a real object, but I strongly suggest not doing so.

---

Instead, find a *new* way to represent the data, and parse it into an array.

Maybe, using Javascript's string functions:

```
<input type="hidden" name="" value="1,12,2,3,4" id="rollNumber"/>
```

Then:

```
rollNo = document.getElementById("rollNumber").value.split(/,/);
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JJ54C/):

[image: Demonstration of technique]

It's hard to tell just from the console output (which always has to be string-like so that you, as a human, can read it), but these are two very different things.

---

Alternatively, if you need to keep the `input` field value the way it is, you could parse it as JSON using `JSON.parse` (though you have to jump through hoops to make this available on all but the very latest browsers).

Comment: Only split using (,) as a parameter returns '[' ']' bracket as well.  But if i use    document.getElementById("rollNumber").value.replace(/[\[\]\s]+/g,'').split(/,/)  then it is working fine. Thank you.

Comment: @Prakash: That's why, in my suggestion using `split`, the input does not have the `[` or `]` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Value is a string, not an object. You will need to convert it. I would do something like this.

```
<input type="hidden" name="" value="1,12,2,3,4" id="rollNumber"/>
```

```
rollNo = document.getElementById("rollNumber").value;
var myArray = rollNo.split(',');
```

Comment: Only split using (,) as a parameter returns '[' ']' bracket as well.  But if i use    document.getElementById("rollNumber").value.replace(/[\[\]\s]+/g,'').split(/,/)  then it is working fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How you are iterating it ?

Keep in mind that document.getElementById('').value will return a string.

Try this

```
<input type="hidden" name="" value="1,12,2,3,4" id="rollNumber"/> 

rollNo = document.getElementById("rollNumber").value.split(',');
for(i=0;i<rollNo.length;i++){
console.log(rollNo[i]);
}
```

Comment: Only split using (,) as a parameter returns '[' ']' bracket as well.  But if i use    document.getElementById("rollNumber").value.replace(/[\[\]\s]+/g,'').split(/,/)  then it is working fine. Thank you.

Comment: You haven't checked my markup. Do you ?

My value in hidden input does not have '[' or ']'. Please notice the answer of user 999 too :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like JSON string, you have to parse it using eval. You may use below code to retrieve each number

```
var rollNo = document.getElementById("rollNumber").value;
var rollNoArray = eval(rollNo);
for(var i=0;i<rollNoArray .length;i++){
    alert(rollNoArray [i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this working demonstration: [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u8Uen/)

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<input type="hidden" name="" value="[1, 12, 2, 3, 4]" id="rollNumber"/> 
<script>
rollNo = document.getElementById("rollNumber").value;
var arrayvar=eval(rollNo);
var urstring="";
for (i=0;i<arrayvar.length;i++)
{
    urstring+=arrayvar[i]+" ";
}
document.write(urstring);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to stick with the given format and you don't want to or can't use `JSON.parse` this might do the trick:

```
document.getElementById("rollNumber").value.replace(/[\[\]\s]+/g,'').split(/,/)
```